# Express JS download zip via endpoint

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm trying to allow a user to be able to download a zip folder from a server via an express JS api call. I've created my folder with: `zip -r download.zip folder-to-zip` and am struggling to get it to download.

It seems if I make a GET request to some endpoint, it only downloads it to the server rather than the browser, my endpoint is:

```js
router.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  res.download('download.zip')
})
```

I need to attach something to a button that'll download this zip folder.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, I'll update my answer when I have.

But I think doing something like:

```
router.get('/download', (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-type','application/zip');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/download.zip');
})
```

This is usually how I download files via express.

Comment: You're using a file to download, I need to download a whole folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I've just tested the above code locally, I had a local file called download.zip and it downloaded the entire zip file, allowing it's contents to be extracted. Have you tried the above code?